# Error while running multiple SFSpeechRecognitionTask in background

Tags: ios, swift, speech, sfspeechrecognizer

As per requirement of the App I am developing, I have to pass multiple audio files to `SFSpeechRecognizer` and get the transcription in return.
I did it in two ways

**First Method - Using Recursion (Running correctly, you can skip it if you want)**

I have first completed this task by getting transcription one by one. i.e when the `SFSpeechRecognitionTask` gets completed, the result gets saved and the process runs again through a recursive call.

```
class Transcription
{
    let url = [URL(fileURLWithPath: "sad")]
    var fileCount = 3
    let totalFiles = 4;

    func getTranscriptionRecursive()
    {
        getTranscriptionOfAudioFile(atURL: url[fileCount], fileCount: fileCount, totalFiles: totalFiles) { (result) in

            if(self.fileCount <= self.totalFiles)
            {
                self.fileCount = self.fileCount+1
                self.getTranscriptionRecursive()
            }
        }
    }

    func getTranscriptionOfAudioFile(atURL url: URL, fileCount: Int, totalFiles: Int, completion: @escaping ((SFSpeechRecognitionResult?)->Void))
    {
        let request = SFSpeechURLRecognitionRequest(url: url)

        request.shouldReportPartialResults = false

        let recognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer(locale: Locale(identifier: "en-US"))

        if (recognizer?.isAvailable)! {

            recognizer?.recognitionTask(with: request) { result, error in
                //error handling
                completion(result)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This method worked great but it takes way too much time as each `SFSpeechRecognizer` request takes time to complete.

---

**Second Method - Using Loop and Background Thread
(This one is having the issue)**

I tried to create multiple requests and execute them in background at once.
For that I created a For Loop till the count of audio files, and in that loop I called the function to create `SFSpeechRecognizer` Request and task.

```
for index in 0..<urls.count
        {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        self.getTranscriptionOfAudio(atURL: self.urls[index]) { (result, myError, message) in

            //error handling

            //process Results
            }
        }
    }
```

where as the function to get speech recognition results is

```
func getTranscriptionOfAudio(atURL audioURL: URL?, completion: @escaping ((SFSpeechRecognitionResult? , Error?, String?)->Void))
    {
    let request = SFSpeechURLRecognitionRequest(url: audioURL!)

    request.shouldReportPartialResults = false

    let recognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer(locale: Locale(identifier: "en-US"))

    if (recognizer?.isAvailable)! {

        recognizer?.recognitionTask(with: request) { result, error in
            //error handling

            completion(results,nil,nil)
        }
    } else {
        completion(nil,nil,"Reognizer could not be initialized");
    }
}
```

When I run this code, only one task executes and other tasks give this error

> +[AFAggregator logDictationFailedWithError:] Error
>   Domain=kAFAssistantErrorDomain Code=209 "(null)"

I searched this error on internet but there is no documentation that contains its details.

It might be due to running `SFSpeechRecognitionTask` in parallel, but in official Apple documents [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/speech/sfspeechrecognizer) they didn't forbid to do so, as we can create `SFSpeechRecognitionRequest` object separately. We don't use singleton object of `SFSpeechRecognizer`

let me know if anyone has any idea what is going on and what you suggest me to do.

Comment: wondering if have you solved it? Talha Ahmad Khan

Comment: I have the same issue. I'd like to create a small pool of recognition tasks. I suspect running multiple tasks at once isn't supported.

Comment: @Talha Ahmad Khan Did you find a solution for this?